# Clean/mock API database when using Angular2 E2E testing

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm using Rails 5 API backend and Angular2 frontend.  I'm testing my API using request and model rspec tests and testing the Angular side using Protractor.

Testing the API is easy since after each test the test database is purged, this ensures that the next test is working from a clean slate.  My issue is with the Protractor tests.

I know E2E testing *should* be hitting the backend but my issue is that if I have a Protractor test that POSTs to the create action of the API (inserting a record into the development database on the Rails side), then this record is still there for the next test and so on so I am not working from a clean predictable state for the next test.

I'm not seeing a whole lot on mocking the backend in Angular2 on line (http-backend seems to be what's used a lot for Angular(1)js).  Is it the case that if I do add a record in a given test that then I need to manually perform some kind of cleanup for the next test?  This is what I find myself doing right now and it seems like a very tedious approach.  So (hopefully) without falling into the box of "opinion related question" I was wondering what the general approach is for this senario?

Comment: It is up to you if you need to preform real e2e test (including unmocked backend) or UI functional test. The term e2e is really obscure in this context.

Comment: So if I have a fully tested API then I should be looking more at unit testing on the Angular side?  But... IF I was to stay with Protractor and stick to the principles of E2E testing then I still have the issue of the backend database changing from test to test.  So I guess the real question is how do people work with E2E testing in an everyday sense?

Comment: Functional tests shouldn't be confused with unit tests. I see no reason to test both frontend and backend in the same test, at least for destructive operations. Your backend should be already covered with tests, including e2e/functional tests, shouldn't it? A2 module mocking [isn't supported](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3092) yet. If you don't want to maintain a separate build for tests, you can mock HTTP requests [with Protractor](https://github.com/atecarlos/protractor-http-mock) or [with Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server).